# flask importerror: cannot import name storage

Tags: python, flask

I try to use flask-cloudy to uploads files, but I can't import storage (a model in flask-cloudy)
this is how I config it :

```
class DevelopmentConfig():
    DEBUG = True
    SECRET_KEY = 'I_will_never_told_you'
    STORAGE_PROVIDER = "LOCAL"
    STORAGE_CONTAINER = "./data"
    STORAGE_KEY = ""
    STORAGE_SECRET = ""
    STORAGE_SERVER = True
```

and I initialise it in app/**init**.py :

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, request, url_for, g
from .main import main as main_blueprint
from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
from config import DevelopmentConfig
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_cloudy import Storage     #import Storage

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.session_protection = 'strong'
login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfig)
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint, url_prefix='/auth')
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    storage = Storage()     
    storage.init_app(app)        #initialise it 

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        from .models import User
        try:
            user = User.get(User.id == int(user_id))
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            user = None
        return user

    @login_manager.unauthorized_handler
    def unauthorized_callback():
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

    return app
```

then I try to import storage in app/main/views.py:
I had try

```
from app import storage
```

and

```
from .. import storage
```

and

```
from ..__init__ import storage
```

but it still can't work well
when I use `from app import storage` and `from .. import storage`
it grow up like this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import create_app
  File "/home/lc/workspace/homeworkAdminSystem/app/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
  File "/home/lc/workspace/homeworkAdminSystem/app/main/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import views, errors
  File "/home/lc/workspace/homeworkAdminSystem/app/main/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .. import storage
ImportError: cannot import name storage
```

and when I tryed `from ..__init__ import storage`
it appear :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import create_app
  File "/home/lc/workspace/homeworkAdminSystem/app/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
  File "/home/lc/workspace/homeworkAdminSystem/app/main/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import views, errors
  File "/home/lc/workspace/homeworkAdminSystem/app/main/views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ..__init__ import storage
  File "/home/lc/workspace/homeworkAdminSystem/app/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
  File "/home/lc/workspace/homeworkAdminSystem/app/auth/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/lc/workspace/homeworkAdminSystem/app/auth/views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..models import db, User, Homework, Score
  File "/home/lc/workspace/homeworkAdminSystem/app/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .__init__ import login_manager
ImportError: cannot import name login_manager
```

and here is my models(app/models) in it I used `from .__init__ import login_manager` but it worked well, so I am confuse of it ,so how can I import storage in my views.py?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your storage initialisation outside of the `create_app` function.

The `storage` variable right now is only accessible inside the `create_app` function.

Comment: oh，I wish I can get my PC right now，I will try tomorrow morning，Thank you.

Comment: I had try to put storage initialistaion outside of create_app, but still can't work. whatever thanks.

Comment: Maybe get rid oft the function altogether? Or you could return the storage variable too

Comment: I had tried return storage yesterday but it can t work well，maybe something wrong when I config it，because the example in github the writer put all config and  initialistaion together and I tried it，and it works. maybe I can just put all this in my views.py